# I'm trying to test a List of object using Mockito Java Spring boot but I'm getting error (saveAll should return List)

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit4

Good day, I'm new to Mockito and I'm trying to test a list of objects.

```
@Mock
private AudienceCodeTypeRepository repository;

@Mock
private Page<AudienceCodeType> page;

private AudienceCodeTypeService underTest;

@Mock
private List<AudienceCodeType> listOfObject;

List<GenericReferenceCodeInput> testObj;

public void testBulkSave() throws Exception {

    AudienceCodeType obj = new AudienceCodeType();

    obj.setInternalid(1L);
    obj.setCode("1");
    obj.setLegend("Test");
    obj.setStatus("A");
    obj.setAudit(new Audit());
    listOfObject.add(obj);

    listOfObject = Arrays.asList(obj);
    doReturn(obj).when(repository).saveAll(listOfObject);       

    GenericReferenceCodeInput actualProduct = new GenericReferenceCodeInput();
    actualProduct.setCode("1");
    actualProduct.setLegend("Test");
    actualProduct.setStatus("A");
    testObj.add(actualProduct);
    testObj = Arrays.asList(actualProduct);

    List<AudienceCodeType> testObject = (List<AudienceCodeType>) underTest.bulkInsert(testObj);
    assertEquals(true, obj.getClass().isInstance(actualProduct));
    assertEquals(listOfObject.get(0), testObject.get(0));
    assertEquals(listOfObject.get(1), testObject.get(1));
    assertEquals(listOfObject.get(2), testObject.get(2));
    assertEquals(listOfObject.get(3), testObject.get(3));
}
```

}

but I'm getting an error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrontTypeOfReturnValue
>   AudienceCodeType cannot be returned by saveAll() saveAll should return
>   List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited code.....

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void testBulkSaveAllPass() throws Exception {
    List<AudienceCodeType> result = new ArrayList<AudienceCodeType>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2557717330663162468L;
    {
        add(new AudienceCodeType() {{
            setInternalid(1L);
            setCode("1");
            setLegend("Test1");
            setDescription("JUnit Test 1");
            setStatus("A");
            setAudit(new Audit());
        }});
        add(new AudienceCodeType() {{
            setInternalid(2L);
            setCode("2");
            setLegend("Test2");
            setDescription("JUnit Test 2");
            setStatus("A");
            setAudit(new Audit());
        }});
    }};

    doReturn(result).when(repository).saveAll(any(List.class));
    doReturn(Optional.of(new AudienceCodeType()),
             Optional.of(new AudienceCodeType()))
                .when(repository).findOne(any(Example.class));

    MultipleEntitiesReport<AudienceCodeType> testObject = 
            underTest.bulkInsert(new ArrayList<GenericReferenceCodeInput>(){
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -6802324625468779673L;
            {
                add(new GenericReferenceCodeInput() {{
                    setCode("1");
                    setLegend("Test1");
                    setDescription("JUnit Test 1");
                    setStatus("A");
                }});
                add(new GenericReferenceCodeInput() {{
                    setCode("2");
                    setLegend("Test2");
                    setDescription("JUnit Test 2");
                    setStatus("A");
                }});
            }});
    assertEquals("Test Return", false, testObject.getPass().isEmpty());     
    assertEquals("Test First Object Code", result.get(0).getCode(), testObject.getPass().get(0).getCode());
    assertEquals("Test Second Object Code", result.get(1).getCode(), testObject.getPass().get(1).getCode());

    Mockito.verify(repository, times(2)).findOne(any(Example.class));
    Mockito.verify(repository, times(1)).saveAll(any(List.class));
}
```

This is the approach I did, hopefully this might help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
 AudienceCodeType obj = new AudienceCodeType();
```

with

```
List<AudienceCodeType> obj = Collections.singletonList(newAudienceCodeType());
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I'm confused now how a'm I going to add an object to it ? do u have an example ?.